# How can I make sure conditional rendering in event handlers in tables in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a table in React. The table has some data which consists of two spans. I don't want to show the span except the user hovers over the table. I have created the listeners and all of that but if I set it to display block, it looks really ugly. I also tried other display styles like table cell and inline-block and they all looked terrible.

My goal is to make this show just as it was when it wasn't displayed to none.

This is the JSX code

```
class Table extends Component{
  state={
    isHovered: false
  }
  toggleHover= ()=> {
    this.setState(prevState => ({isHovered: !prevState.isHovered}));
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
         <div className={Styles.PageDetails}>
           <div>
            <h1>Table</h1>
           </div>
           <div className={Styles.TableNav} onClick={this.props.clicked}>
             <div></div>
             <div></div>
             <div></div>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div className={Styles.Table}>
           <table>
             <tr>
               <th>S/N</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Description</th>
               <th>Date</th>
               <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
    <td onMouseEnter={this.toggleHover} onMouseLeave={this.toggleHover}><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</span> <span style={{
      display: this.state.isHovered ? 'block' : null
    }}>elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec.</span></td>
</tr>
           </table>
```

CSS

```
.Table td span:last-of-type{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using CSS `visibility` property instead of modifying display:

```
visibility: this.state.isHovered ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
```

By default, a `span` tag styles itself as `display: inline;`. This is why you're experiencing the style difference. You could use:

```
display: this.state.isHovered ? 'inline' : 'none'
```

But you're better off with the `visibility` property here.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. Tottaly forgot about the visibility property

Comment: The visibiity property is better. I used the inline property and it was still messed up.

Comment: Odd that `inline` would cause any styling difference... Either way, glad `visibility` worked out!